# Dep Ensure Not Working Following New Computer Install From Git

Tags: go, dependencies, package, dep

I just finished up my first big project for a software engineering company, but when I tried to install the code on my personal computer tonight I am having trouble with Go. I set up my GOPATH and GOROOT and things seem to be okay. Here are those:

[image: $GOPATH & $GOROOT]

Everything worked GREAT today on the work computer, but now its just a pain. I'm getting all kinds of errors, but the biggest is that it "cannot find package." It is also giving me an error for "use of internal package not allowed" when it worked just fine on my work computer. I worked primarily in the front end so I'm a little ignorant on the subject, but I texted a co-intern and he didn't know either. I am thinking its my Go installation.

We used dep ensure for the dependencies and it is looking in the wrong place. for the vendor files. Here is an example of the file structure:

[image: File Structure]

I would LOVE some help with this because I was so excited to show this thing off we worked so hard on, If anyone is interested here is the GitHub link!

https://github.com/acstech/doppler-events

Thank you everyone!

Comment: try removing the `vendor` directory and run again `dep ensure`

Comment: Okay so I did that and it's giving me a new error that is basically saying I can't use one type of dateTime with another because the paths are different of where they are referenced. Here it is: ./testSend.go:154:14: cannot use dateTime (type *"github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes/timestamp".Timestamp) as type *"github.com/acstech/doppler-events/vendor/github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes/timestamp".Timestamp in field value

Comment: Ok, but I think that at least now `dep ensure` is working and got your dependencies right?

Comment: I will try a fresh install this afternoon, but it still gave me the "internal package cannot be used."  I will try to run it as soon as I get the install dockerbuilt

Comment: Did a fresh install and ran "dep ensure" after cloning down but still has the initial issues I have mentioned above.

Comment: okay so I fixed it. I had "go" spelt like "Go" in my $HOME... I am so dumb, but thanks for the help!!